# Why doesn't GDB recognize my library's symbols?

Tags: gdb, static-libraries

I have a project hierarchy similar to the following:

```
src/
  code.c
ext/
  lib/
    lib.c
    lib.a
bin/
  bin-code (+x)
  obj/
    code.o
```

- `lib.c` compiles into `lib.a` using the `-g2` flag and then `ar`.
- `code.c` compiles into `bin/obj/code.o` using the `-g2` flag.
- `lib.a` and `code.o` are then linked into binary `bin-code`.

I'm facing a bug within `bin-code` and I'm trying to use *GDB* to load the symbols/source for `lib` so I can examine it with TUI.

I'm adding a breakpoint for a function inside `lib.c`, which it seems to find as it echos out an address and says it successfully set the breakpoint.

When I run the program and hit the breakpoint, I open TUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, but it claims no source could be found.

Two things worth mentioning:

1. I have used `set substitute-path` due to the fact my build system ([Tup](http://gittup.org/tup)) uses a FUSE filesystem to enforce read/write operations.
2. I have tried adding `directory` entries to the search paths, to no avail.

Am I missing something here? Is there a command I can issue GDB in order for it to rescan directories or something? I can't get the library's source to show up, even though it appears symbols have been loaded.

Comment: Did you remember to compile your library in debug mode?

Comment: @HSchmale `lib.c compiles into lib.a using the -g2 flag and then ar` Yes, unless `ar` has a debug flag.

Comment: I've found it best if I compile using `gcc` to build with the object files as inputs. I've never had trouble with a library that I built this way.

Comment: @HSchmale that's great, but I can't do that :)

Comment: Run `objdump -W bin-code`. In its output, do you see a `DW_AT_name` attribute with value `lib.c`? If so, can you show us the value of the `DW_AT_comp_dir` attribute that comes right after it?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `objdump` isn't found on my computer. Using a mac, I should mention.

Comment: OK. OSX has `dwarfdump`, but I don't know what its output looks like. Also, what C compiler are you using?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick you know I didn't think about until now but I'm using clang and then GDB. That could very well be the source of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely gdb fails to find sources of you static library and can't show it's source code.

This may happen if binary was moved to another machine after it was built or sources were moved to another directory. In this case you should properly `set substitute-path`. You can see where gdb tries to find sources of static library (`lib.c`) using `info sources` command. Compare this path with the one where `lib.c` is actually located and this should help to set proper [path substitution](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html).